# Authentication while UI rendering without login page

Tags: python, django, authentication, cookies, ldap

I have a view in Django which renders html page. I need to do authentication before rendering the page. The link to open this page would be provided in another application built using groovy. 
On clicking the link, the UI should be rendered directly without any login page.

At present I am using the @login_required decorator which opens the login page before rendering the UI. I want to bypass or use another mechanism which would do the authentication without showing the login page.

PS: I don't have much knowledge regarding authentication.

Comment: *"the authentication without showing the login page"*, you mean token authentication?

Comment: Hi @ArakkalAbu , can you suggest how it could be done using token authentication. Even I though about it, but unaware as to how to do it on clicking a link.